# Generating tuples based on indexing from 0

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I use this code (Python 2.7):

```
X = [(i, i+1) for i in range(4)]
print(X)
```

I simply get:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

However, In my project, I shouldn't have `(3, 4)` because my indexing starts at 0 ( i.e., for 4, the indexing is 0,1,2,3). Instead, it should be `(0, 3)` so that I get all tuples in the range of the indexing `[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (0, 3)]`. How can I modify the code above to reflect my indexing?

Comment: `Instead, it should be (0, 3) so that I get all tuples in the range of the indexing` Can you please explain what this means?

Comment: I mean the pairs are in the range of 0,1,2,3

Comment: So why don't you want (0, 2) and (1, 3)?

Comment: If the idea is overlapping, shouldn't the last tuple be `(3,0)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the second item in each pair to be `i+1` unless `i==3`, when you want it to be 0:

```
X = [(i, i+1 if i!=3 else 0) for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: Oh! Isn't that simple! Thank you so much

Comment: @chrisz It should be fine too, chris